# Usages of Kanou and meaning of shitsudou

Tags: words

So recently I've been interested in quotes from the Japanese version of LoL.
Blitzcrank's quote is "起動完了、しつどう可能"

The English version is "fired up and ready to serve"

https://youtu.be/kZ5LyBQAT0E?t=28

Firstly, I understand 'kanou' means possible or feasible and usually states that something is available for something to be done to it such as 購入可能 meaning now available for purchase. But the usage in this case has confused me a bit. Can it mean 'ready' as well.

Secondly, i can't find the meaning of shitsudou anywhere, (have i herd it wrong?).

Or have i completely misunderstood the meaning of the second half of the quote?

Comment: I think you probably mean 出動 (し**ゅ**つどう, to dispatch etc.)?

Comment: ah ok that makes sense. Thanks. question can be closed. idk how.

Comment: I don't think you should close it because your second question is still valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have i herd it wrong

I think they probably meant 出動(し*ゅ*つどう Shu-tu-do-u) rather than しつどう.

> Can it mean 'ready' as well

It *doesn't necessarily* mean 'ready' according to several [dictionaries](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD-465472), but it does make sense.

If I were to translate that sentence and told to preserve the word 'ready,' I would say

> 起動完了、出動 *準備完了*

which uses words that translates to 'ready.'